# Images overlaying the header on scroll down in Safari Browser

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

In WordPress, I'm using the "Flip Box" Widget(provided by Elementor) but there is an issue when I check my website on Safari Browser. The issue is that Images overlaying the header on scroll down in Safari Browser. It's working fine on other browsers like Chrome, Firefox.

This is what I found on Elementor official documents

> The Safari browser is partially incompatible with the 3D Depth effect
> on mobile. If 3D Depth is used, portions of the flip box may show
> through the Nav Menu dropdown. It is not possible to use the 3D Flip
> Box widget and the Nav Menu widget with IOS due to issues with Safari
> being unable to support this option. We advise modifying the content
> for mobile in this case with the “hide section” option in the
> section’s Advanced tab in Responsive > Visibility.

I want the animation should be working fine and the overlay issue should be solved somehow.

Here is my **Site Link:** http://goodfdev.wpengine.com/favorite-things-2020/

Can anybody help to get rid of this issue?

Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this problem using Flipbox 3D effect - Elementor add this css

```css
.elementor-widget-flip-box {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```